# ReactJS as Plain Html

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, gatsby

I'm trying to serve my existing ReactJS app as a single plain HTML file. I want to eliminate the use of node server and basically want a pre-complied version which I can use to run it in the browser.(like index.html) I referred to create-react-app but it seems tedious to integrate my already built react app as a create-react-app project. Can someone help ?

Comment: Take a look at [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org). I'm afraid there is no simple way to simply generate a single plain html file.

Comment: @Bloatlord 
 But does Gatsby will generate a single HTML file like I want, if I manage to migrate my existing react app into Gatsby ?